# What is the math beyond Aloe polyphylla?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, symmetry

There is a plant called Aloe polyphylla that grows in an eye-catching spiral pattern.

Is there some math beyond Aloe polyphylla?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_polyphylla

[image]

(photo credit: wikimedia)

Comment: I don't know enough about this specific plant, and haven't watched these videos in a while, but it's likely that Vi Hart's three-video series "Doodling in Math: Spirals, Fibonacci, and Being a Plant" ([part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahXIMUkSXX0)) is relevant. If I recall correctly, she explains that not every similar pattern is directly related to the Fibonacci sequence, but that's part of a family of closely related ideas which have something to say about plant patterns like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but spirals in Nature are often related with the golden mean and the Fibonacci sequence:

- Check [here](https://math.temple.edu/~reich/Fib/fibo.html)
- Or [this](https://momath.org/home/fibonacci-numbers-of-sunflower-seed-spirals/), about sunflowers

Comment: Google *Phyllotaxis* .. many beautiful examples can be found. Fibonacci sequence has the well known property which Nature uses for growth and material economy or space accomodation. It has a visual presentation pleases as a spiral appealing to pattern recognition in mathematics, not man, but God made.  The aloe arrangement can be seen in branch attachment points of coconut, palm, pineapple, pine cones.. never tired of looking at them.

If there is no fault in spiral ordering an exponetial tiling would result , but Fibonacci breaks the symmetry in a very interesting way.